# mutt: define which headers are displayed (in compose)

Tags: mutt

When composing a message in `mutt`, I see the following headers:

```
    From: 
      To: 
      Cc:
     Bcc:
 Subject:
Reply-To:
     Fcc: ~/.mail/sent
     Mix: <no chain defined>
Security: None
```

I don't know what the `Mix:` header is for, and I don't think I will ever need it. Similarly, I will not need to edit the `Reply-To:` header.

These two useless lines are taking up valuable space. Is it possible to remove these headers entirely? Can I specify which headers are displayed in the compose menu?

Comment: According to the [Mutt Manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-2.html), `Mix` is for sending anonymous messages via `mixmaster` (whatever that means)

Comment: Sooo, is proofing by looking through the source code that these options are not available (and therefore saying "no, not possible - but look here, a modification") to the above questions a credible source? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got a (very hacky) solution. Answer: It is possible to remove these headers by editing `mutt`'s code, but not possible in any other way so far.

First of all, there is no flag or any check in `mutt`'s source code to prevent these headers from appearing in the compose menu window. At least I didn't see any.

So it is not possible to specify which headers are displayed in the compose menu without having to edit `mutt`'s code.

I had a look at the source code (`apt-get source mutt`) and found out, where `mutt` draws its headers, when you compose a mail.

The important parts lie in `compose.c`:

```
[...]

[line 60]
//  HDR_REPLYTO,

[...]

[line 77]
static char *Prompts[] =
{
  "From: ",
  "To: ",
  "Cc: ",
  "Bcc: ",
  "Subject: ",
//  "Reply-To: ",
  "Fcc: "
};

[...]

[line 251]
static void draw_envelope (HEADER *msg, char *fcc)
{
  draw_envelope_addr (HDR_FROM, msg->env->from);
  draw_envelope_addr (HDR_TO, msg->env->to);
  draw_envelope_addr (HDR_CC, msg->env->cc);
  draw_envelope_addr (HDR_BCC, msg->env->bcc);
  mvprintw (HDR_SUBJECT, 0, TITLE_FMT, Prompts[HDR_SUBJECT - 1]);
  mutt_paddstr (W, NONULL (msg->env->subject));
//  draw_envelope_addr (HDR_REPLYTO, msg->env->reply_to);
  mvprintw (HDR_FCC, 0, TITLE_FMT, Prompts[HDR_FCC - 1]);
  mutt_paddstr (W, fcc);

  if (WithCrypto)
    redraw_crypt_lines (msg);

#undef MIXMASTER
#ifdef MIXMASTER
  redraw_mix_line (msg->chain);
#endif

[...]

[line 564]
//      case OP_COMPOSE_EDIT_REPLY_TO:
//  menu->redraw = edit_address_list (HDR_REPLYTO, &msg->env->reply_to);
//        mutt_message_hook (NULL, msg, M_SEND2HOOK);
//  break;
```

Make these changes according to the code above:

- comment out line 60, the `HDR_REPLYTO` enum -> vanishes the `Reply-To` header
- comment out the "Reply-To: " string in the `Prompts` array -> vanishes the `Reply-To` header string
- comment out `draw_envelope_addr (HDR_REPLYTO, msg->env->reply_to);` -> vanishes the `Reply-To` header
- comment out lines `564`-`567` to avoid compiling errors due to the lack of `HDR_REPLYTO` -> vanishes the `Reply-To` header editing option
- add `#undef MIXMASTER` before the def check (or maybe add this line earlier to avoid any checks to be positive) -> vanishes the `Mix` header.

Then `./configure` and `make` to create your personalized `mutt`. You might have to fix some compiling and configuration issues.

It worked on `mutt-1.5.21`.

I don't really know how mutt's code works, I see that they use `curses` windows. If someone spends more time understanding this code and why it works, please post a follow-up.

Answer (score 4):

You set the headers you want to display in `muttrc`, like so:

```
# headers to show
ignore *                                      # ignore all headers
unignore from: to: cc: date: subject:         # show only these
hdr_order from: to: cc: date: subject:        # and in this order
```

Comment: thanks, but this has effect only in the pager (i.e. for received messages), but not in the compose menu.

Comment: Works for me: what else is in your `.muttrc`?

Comment: well, usual stuff. about 50 lines. But nothing what I could see would interfere with `ignore`

Comment: Have you set `edit_headers`?

Comment: no, I don't have `edit_headers` set

Comment: I assumed you would have, add `set edit_headers` and see if that works.

Comment: When I add `set edit_headers = yes` then I can edit the headers together with the body of my message. But this is not what I meant. Besides, when I return from the editor back to `compose menu` and see the headers, I still see the full headers (as before)

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. I can still see `Bcc:` etc. in compose mode and my editor (`vim`). I have `edit_headers` set.

Answer (score 3):

If using vim:

```
set editor = "vim -c '/Mix: /d|/Reply-To: /d'"
```

Comment: Hacky, but does the trick. Linux in a nutshell.